# Unified Logs | macOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, logs

I have macOS unified logs from System A in *.logarchive* format. Any attempts to parse the *.logarchive* in System B using `log show` command provides following error:

```
bash-3.2#log show /tmp/unifiedlogsv2/unifiedlogs.logarchive
        ==========
    /private/tmp/unifiedlogsv2/unifiedlogs.logarchive
        ==========
    log: Archive format needs updating (to version 3), doing so will render the archive unreadable by older tools.
    Re-run log with --force if you want to allow this upgrade
```

When run with `--force` option, the following error is displayed:

```
bash-3.2# log show --force /tmp/unifiedlogsv2/unifiedlogs.logarchive|more
log: warning: The log archive contains partial or missing metadata
log: Could not open log archive: The log archive format is corrupt and cannot be read
==========
/private/tmp/unifiedlogsv2/unifiedlogs.logarchive
==========
```

The same logarchive opens fine in Console. My objective is to parse the logarchive using the `log show` command. Any suggestions how to do so?

Comment: How did you make the specific log file? I'm guessing it's corrupt and not that you have a bad syntax. Can you verify that `log stream` is working to stream the unified feed that's not been processed or redirected to another file?

Comment: I used rsync to copy all the contents of /private/var/db/diagnostics/ and /private/var/db/uuidtext into a directory.Then used 'sudo mv -i -v /tmp/unifiedlogs/* /tmp/unifiedlogsv2/unifiedlogs.logarchive' .As already mentioned ,the same logarchive opens fine in Console

Comment: Thanks. I didn’t ask if console can open your collection, I was trying to discern if the log system was broken on the source mac. No worries if you don’t see value in clarifying / updating. Was just hoping to get you an answer or the beginning of one. You’ve got that now.

Answer (score 3):

The `man log` page shows two switches, `--file file` and `--archive archive`. You will likely need to include one of them when working with archives from another system which didn't originate on the local system.

```
log show [--archive archive | --file file] [--predicate filter] [--source] [--style default | compact | json | syslog] [--color auto | always | none]
     [--start date/time] [--end date/time] [--[no-]info] [--[no-]debug] [--[no-]signpost] [--last time [m|h|d]] [--timezone local | timezone]
```

The man page goes on to detail those 2 switches like so:

```
    --archive archive
                     Display events stored in the given archive. The archive 
                     must be a valid log archive bundle with the suffix
                     .logarchive.

    --file file      Display events stored in the given .tracev3 file. In order 
                     to be decoded, the file must be contained within
                     a valid .logarchive bundle, or part of the system logs 
                     directory.
```

#### Example

Since you're working with `.logarchive` formatted files you likely want to use the `--archive` switch:

```
$ log show --archive /tmp/unifiedlogsv2/unifiedlogs.logarchive
```

Comment: The -file command requires .tracev3 format.While using --archive does the trick.Thanks

Comment: @swastibhushandeb - thanks I updated the A'er to include these details.